# Como implementar uma arraylist em uma condição?

Tags: java, arraylist, condição

Preciso que nesse código haja uma classe `Estudante`, uma `Professor` e outra `Disciplina`. Estou tentando limitar os estudantes da classe `Disciplina` em 50 com uma `ArrayList` e uma condição, mas talvez elas estejam em lugares errados ou é algo muito simples que não consigo enxergar.

Como faço pra dizer: se a quantidade de estudantes for > 50 então mostrar : "Sala lotada"?

Porque basicamente um objeto disciplina pode ter no máximo 50 estudantes.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {



   Estudante e1 = new Estudante();
    e1.nome = "Carlos Jr";
    e1.nmatricula = "420.666";
    e1.ano= "2017";
    e1.idade= "15";

  Professor p1 = new Professor();
   p1.nome = "Kira Yagami";
   p1.ano = "2017";
   p1.especialidade = "Tecnologia da Informação";

    Disciplina d1 = new Disciplina();
    d1.professor = p1;
    d1.estudante = e1;

  if(est>50){
            System.out.println("Sala lotada. Mais de 50 alunos!");
        }
      else{
          System.out.println("Sala com menos de 50 alunos!");
        }

}
}


class Estudante{
  String nome;
  String nmatricula;
  String ano;
  String idade;
}
class Professor{
  String nome;
  String ano;
  String especialidade;
}
class Disciplina{
  Professor professor;
  ArrayList<Estudantes> estudantes;

  public Disciplina(){
    this.estudantes = new ArrayList<Estudantes>();
  }

  public void quantidadeDeEstudantes(){
    for(int i =0;i<this.estudantes.size();i++){
      String est = this.estudantes.get(i).nome;
    }
  }
}
```

---

O código tinha uns erros de digitação, mas considerando esse:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

    class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {



       Estudante e1 = new Estudante();
        e1.nome = "Justos Walita";
        e1.nmatricula = "420.666";
        e1.ano= "2017";
        e1.idade= "15";

      Professor p1 = new Professor();
       p1.nome = "Kira Yagami";
       p1.ano = "2017";
       p1.especialidade = "Tecnologia de TI";

        Disciplina d1 = new Disciplina();
        d1.professor = p1;

        d1.estudantes.add(e1);

      if(this.estudantes.size()>50){
                System.out.println("Sala lotada. Mais de 50 alunos!");
            }
          else{
              System.out.println("Sala com menos de 50 alunos!");
            }

    }
    }


    class Estudante{
      String nome;
      String nmatricula;
      String ano;
      String idade;
    }
    class Professor{
      String nome;
      String ano;
      String especialidade;
    }
    class Disciplina{
      Professor professor;
      ArrayList<Estudante> estudantes;

      public Disciplina(){
        this.estudantes = new ArrayList<Estudante>();
        }

      public void quantidadeDeEstudante(){
        for(int i =0;i<this.estudantes.size();i++){
        }
      }
    }
```

Eu sei que o erro esta na parte:

```
 if(this.estudantes.size()>50){
```

pois esta dizendo que a função q eu fiz n existe. Como arrumo isso?

Comment: Você quer aprender o certo ou só resolver o exercício de qualquer jeito?

Comment: faca um metodo para adicionar estudantes no ArrayList de Disciplina ... antes de adicionar basta verificar se o tamanho do ArrayList é 50

Answer (score -2):

if(this.estudantes.size()>50){

deve ficar assim

//o maximo de estudantes é 50
 if(d1.estudantes.size()<50){

this é utilizado para chamar atributos e métodos da própria classe e o atributo estudantes não foi criado dentro da classe Main e sim dentro da classe Disciplina.

Answer (score -2):

Tente desta forma

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
    
        class Main {
          public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    
    
           Estudante e1 = new Estudante();
            e1.nome = "Justos Walita";
            e1.nmatricula = "420.666";
            e1.ano= "2017";
            e1.idade= "15";
    

          Professor p1 = new Professor();
           p1.nome = "Kira Yagami";
           p1.ano = "2017";
           p1.especialidade = "Tecnologia de TI";
    
            Disciplina d1 = new Disciplina();
            d1.professor = p1;
    
            d1.estudantes.add(e1);
    
          if(d1.quantidadeDeEstudante() >= 50){
                    System.out.println("Sala lotada. Mais de 50 alunos!");
                }
              else{
                  System.out.println("Sala com menos de 50 alunos!");
                }
    
        }
        }
    
    
        class Estudante{
          String nome;
          String nmatricula;
          String ano;
          String idade;
        }
        class Professor{
          String nome;
          String ano;
          String especialidade;
        }
        class Disciplina{
          Professor professor;
          ArrayList<Estudante> estudantes;
    
          public Disciplina(){
            this.estudantes = new ArrayList<Estudante>();
            }
    
          public int quantidadeDeEstudante(){
            return this.estudantes.size();
            }
          }
        }
```

voce pode usar o methodo quantidadeDeEstudante para pegar quantidade de alunos ou simplesmente pode pegar o size d1.estudantes.size()

relacionado a quantidade voce precisa usar o >= 50 assim voce garante que so vai ter 50 alunos se voce usar > 50 ele so vai dar o aviso com 51 registros.

voce pode tentar colocar este trecho como um for assim ele vai ficar inserindo registros ate dar a mensagem que voce espera

```
for (int i = 0; i < 51 ; i++) {

          Professor p1 = new Professor();
           p1.nome = "Kira Yagami";
           p1.ano = "2017";
           p1.especialidade = "Tecnologia de TI";
    
            Disciplina d1 = new Disciplina();
            d1.professor = p1;
    
            d1.estudantes.add(e1);
    
          if(d1.quantidadeDeEstudante() >= 50){
                    System.out.println("Sala lotada. Mais de 50 alunos!");
                }
              else{
                  System.out.println("Sala com menos de 50 alunos!");
                }
    
        }
}
```